# How can my indexes be optimized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, indexing

I have a rails application that talks to Oracle.
In average, I have a request that has the following completion times: (extracted from rails production.log)

```
Completed 200 OK in 85ms (Views: 8.4ms | ActiveRecord: 17.1ms)
```

Basically, I have a Speed table with:

- gps_id
- speed
- timestamp

=> it stores the speed of a given gps device at a given timestamp.

My ActiveRecord request is something like:

```
from = DateTime.strptime(params[:from], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z") 
to = DateTime.strptime(params[:to], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z") 
@speeds = Speed.where('gps_id = ? and timestamp >= ? and timestamp <= ?', gps.id, from, to).order('id desc')
```

=> it retrieves all the speed information between 2 timestamps

As the requests was really slow, I have added 2 indexes on the Speed table:

- one index on the gps_id column
- one index on the timestamp column

I guess this is the first basic approach, but how can this be optimized ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a multi-column index on gps_id and timestamp.  That may improve things. But if you are inserting data more often than you query it, it may have negative consequences elsewhere.

Comment: I'm inserting data very often also. The most important part (the one I really need to be optimized) is the read part though.

Comment: I'd recommend giving it a try and seeing if it improves. If not, take it off again :)

Comment: I have tested it but did not notice any real changes between the multi column index and an index per column. In the controller performing this DB call, there is no loop or real stuff that can cause poor performances though.